# python: filter complex json file

Tags: python, json

Could you please help with advise :)
I have json file like:

```
{
content: {
hostname01: {
active_checks_enabled: "1",
current_attempt: "1",
plugin_output: "SSH OK",
services: {
     monitoring: {
       active_checks_enabled: "0",
       current_attempt: "1",
       current_state: "0",
       downtimes: { },
       plugin_output: "PASV MONITORNG OK",
       last_check: "1437382990",
       problem_has_been_acknowledged: "0",
      }
},
comments: { },
last_notification: "0",
max_attempts: "5"
},
```

how can I format this big file so I only have object like:

```
{
 hostname01:{
   monitoring: {
    current_state: "1"
    }
}
}
```

There two possible current_states: 0, 1.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your JSON file isn't valid - two closing curly brackets are missing, and in valid JSON `keys` need to be enclosed in `"double quotes"`

Comment: Consider setting an accepted answer if it helped with your question.

Answer (score 2):

With [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) input, you can read the data using the module [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (I guess from a file, here I'll just put it into the code):

```
import json

json_data = """
{
    "content": {
        "hostname01": {
            "active_checks_enabled": "1",
            "current_attempt": "1",
            "plugin_output": "SSH OK",
            "services": {
                "monitoring": {
                    "active_checks_enabled": "0",
                    "current_attempt": "1",
                    "current_state": "0",
                    "downtimes": {},
                    "plugin_output": "PASV MONITORNG OK",
                    "last_check": "1437382990",
                    "problem_has_been_acknowledged": "0"
                }
            },
            "comments": {},
            "last_notification": "0",
            "max_attempts": "5"
        }
    }
}
"""

data = json.loads(json_data)
```

Then loop through the hostnames and save the value from `current_state`.

```
reduced_data = {}
for hostname in data["content"]:
    current_state = data["content"][hostname]["services"]["monitoring"]["current_state"]
    reduced_data[hostname] = {"monitoring": {"current_state": current_state}}

print json.dumps(reduced_data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Output:

```
{
    "hostname01": {
        "monitoring": {
            "current_state": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to assure that all `hostname` nodes have the same structure or else catch and handle `KeyError` exceptions.

Comment: You're welcome! Consider upvoting or setting as accepted answer if it helped you :-)